# How to align a picture in a 2 lines fancyhdr header

Tags: header-footer, align, fancyhdr

I use fancyhdr to create my header, i have this code:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{logosmall.jpg} \textbf{Title of my document} \\ 
\hspace{32pt}Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\setlength{\headheight}{45pt}

\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
```

I obtain:

[image]

But I expect:

[image]

How could I align the small picture on the left with the second line ? I tried a lot of different options but nothing works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this, I just stack the header text above the baseline, after the graphic.

Here, I substitute the `totpages` package for `lastpage`, as I don't have access to the latter.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a4]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine,lipsum}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\usepackage{totpages}%\usepackage{lastpage}

\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1.5cm]{logosmall.jpg} 
\hspace{32pt}\Longstack[l]{\textbf{Title of my document} \\ 
Page \thepage{} of %
\ref{TotPages}%\pageref{LastPage}%
}}
\setlength{\headheight}{45pt}

\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Use a bottom aligned `tabular` for the part to the right of the logo:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\setlength{\headheight}{45pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{%
  \includegraphics[width=1cm]{../donald-duck}\quad
  \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}
  \textbf{Title of my document} \\
  Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

Some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: offtopic: +1 for Donald. where did you get the image?

Comment: @naphaneal Somewhere on the net, probably http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/jack-millers-webpage-of-disney/images/5/57/Donald_Duck.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150818042904

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use pre-measured `\parbox`es:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\newsavebox\logobox
\newsavebox\titlebox
\sbox\logobox{\rule{30pt}{30pt}}%replace \rule with your image
\sbox\titlebox{\textbf{Title of my document}}
\fancyhead[L]{%
  \parbox[b]{\wd\logobox}{\usebox\logobox}
  \hspace{5pt}
  \parbox[b]{\wd\titlebox}{%
    \usebox\titlebox \\ 
    \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}
  }
}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyhead[C]{}

\setlength{\headheight}{45pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\null
\end{document}
```

[image: output_crop]